# How to change gallery grid from 4 columns to 3 columns?

Tags: gallery, columns

I'm using WordPress 4.2.2 running Gridsby Child theme (version:1.0.1436164618, latest update). I run my site locally using Xampp.

My question: the Gridsby theme default homepage offers 4-column gallery grid. I would like to shrink the gallery container and to create a 3-column grid instead.

I'm new to WP but I managed to make style changes with Child Theme Configurator. However, not with the gallery grid...I looked everywhere for solutions (including the theme support page but found nothing quite like the issue I'm having).

Can anyone please help me? much appreciated!

Mey

Answer (score 1):

In the admin panel, select custom CSS and add this code:

```
.gallery-image { width: 30%; }
```

That will increase the image width pushing the 4th image down to the next line :)

Comment: No problem! I had the same issue yesterday :)